# Error trying to resolve @expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome in a vanilla React Native project

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-vector-icons

I ran into this strange error today: `` Unable to resolve module `@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome` from `node_modules/react-native-elements/src/checkbox/CheckBoxIcon.js`: @expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome could not be found within the project. ``

This project does not use expo, it was built using vanilla React Native CLI. I checked the `CheckBoxIcon.js` file in `node_modules` and I don't see any references to `@expo`.
Not sure if it matters but I  was working on ane xpo project prior to this but it shouldn't be affecting this separate project I'm working on, will it?

I'm not sure how to fix this, I have tried clearing watchman watches, deleting node_modules and reset metro's cache.

Answer (score 0):

`npm start --reset-cache` did not work but `npm start -- --reset-cache` fixed my issue.